# CSV in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, eda, rmark

[screenshot of my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eTAp.png) How would I organize the data from [https://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/sexlierel.dat](https://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Ewinner/data/sexlierel.dat) to make an accurate analysis? I am having trouble plotting the different types of data with the way it is given to me.

description: [https://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/sexlierel.txt](https://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Ewinner/data/sexlierel.txt)

````
```{r}
data_set <- read.csv("project_data.csv", header = TRUE)

names(data_set)

summary(data_set)

summary(data_set$Gender)

data=data.frame("Gender","Count")

```
````

I am trying to find the relationship with a scatterplot between the number of people in each category (count). I feel like this is difficult to do with the way the data is given. Is there a way I should rearrange my csv file?

````
```{r}
scatter=ggplot(data=data, aes("Gender", "Count")) + geom_point()
```
````

Comment: Hi Rachel, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you be more specific with your question? What kind of plot are you trying to make? Have you tried anything already to build a plot? If so, provide that code too. Also, it will be easier to help if we have the data; see this for some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Try to keep your questions specific and try to cut out unrelated distractions.  This will help answerers find the key problem.  For example, your question is unrelated to r-markdown.  You should omit the tag and remove the Rmd syntax.  Even though your final report will use R markdown, that is not where your current problem is.

Comment: @rachel meredith - what are you actually trying to plot. If you drew the graph by hand with a piece of paper what would it look like? I haven't tested your data but I expect it has 1 and 2 on the x axis and  some dots directly above those at various points. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that data is a "true" CSV file. There are no commas or other delimiters.

you may need to look at read.tsv which is tab separated data?

Comment: I converted the data above into a csv file so I could rearrange the data if I needed to in excel. I am trying to do a scatterplot between the different categories using count as the number of people in each one.

Comment: In your gender example do you simply want the total gender=1 and total gender=2? It is much more reprdocuable to do rearranging in R than in excel

Answer (score 0):

As @CALUM Polwart said, this is not a comma separated file.  It is a fixed width file.  You can also consider spaces as the delimiter.  There are many packages with functions that can help.  For example, you could use

```
library(data.table)
data_set <- fread("so/sexlierel.txt")
```

or

```
library(tidyverse)
data_set <- readr::read_table("so/sexlierel.txt")
```

You may want to set the column names when you read it.  You could use

```
library(tidyverse)
data_set <- readr::read_table("so/sexlierel.txt", col_names = c("gender", "scale", "psm", "ptl", "religiosity", "count"))
```

or

```
library(tidyverse)
data_set <- readr::read_table("so/sexlierel.txt")
names(data_set) <- c("gender", "scale", "psm", "ptl", "religiosity", "count")
```